# how would the memory management work for the C pointer in ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, c, pointers, memory-management

For the following code, essentially, we are calling C functions (funca and funcb) in ObjectiveC and using the C pointer pX. For some reason, we hit EXC_BAD_ACCESS on calling funcb, we figured that it might be related to pX being released or some other memory problems. So the question is, what could go wrong here? If it's really because that pX getting released early, how could we fix it? what's the general practice of doing C inside ObjectiveC, just like this scenario?

.h

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject {
    X *pX;
}
```

.m

```
// calling funca and get the value pX properly set
if (funca(&pX) != 0) {
    // error;
}

// use the pX returned from funca
funcb(pX, ...);
```

Comment: What does `funca` look like? I'm suspicious of the line `funca(&pX)` :) And where are you allocating memory for `*pX` - there is no ARC for C allocations so if it's being released early, it's because you've called `free`

Comment: We don't own funca and funcb, they are from a 3rd party library. *pX is allocated inside funca.

Comment: Oh. In that case it looks like you're doing it right :) Are you 100% sure that MyObject isn't being deallocated (released early etc?)

Comment: MyObject is retained, so I am pretty sure it's not released at the time. :) Could it be some sort of memory alignment problem to cause the EXC_BAD_ACCESS issue?

Comment: As a sanity check, I would initialize `pX` to `NULL` immediately before calling `funca`, then log its value (using the %#x format) immediately after. Repeat this process right before calling `funcb` (assuming the call is in a different scope).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no difference between using C "in Objective C" and using it anywhere else. Vanilla C pointers exist outside the Objective C ref counting system, so they're never released. They're `malloc()`'d and `free()`'d. I would verify that `funca` is doing its job correctly, or maybe post a bit more code.